# Python convert sorted List to Dict with position specified as (key, value) pair

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

Just new to Python, what's the best way to convert a sorted list (yes, elements in list are **unique**):

```
[a0, a1, a2, a3, ..., aj, ... ]
```

to a Dict data type where position looks like following:

```
{
    a0: {'index':0},
    a1: {'index':1},
    a2: {'index':2},
    ...
    aj: {'index':j},
    ...
}
```

Just clarify some concerns here:

- There are actually more pair in the dict such as `{'index': j, 'name': wow, ...}` and convert from list to such dict is necessary, the other properties, such as `'name'` will be added **after** the dict been create, so basically it looks like following, first create the dict, and second based on the key `aj` adding other properties, other properties come later;
- Explicitly define the `index` is necessary, it finally will looks like: `{'index': myFunc(j)}`.

Deeply appreciate your help!

---

What I have tried:

1. tried `l = zip(mylist, range(len(mylist)))` and convert `l` (which looks like `[(a0, 0), (a1, 1), ...]`) to dict, however, it's list with `tuple` inside;
2. tried `d = dict(zip(mylist, range(mylist.len)))` but still need convert `{ai: i}` into `{ai:{'index': i}}` and don't know the brilliant method to solve from here;
3. tried naive `for` loop which works, but not happen with that

Comment: Are your list elements unique ?

Comment: Where did `'name': wow, ...` come from?

Comment: Here's a hint: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: I modified, thanks for point out, @Saicharan S M

Comment: I modified, thanks for point out, @alfasin

Comment: I modified, thanks for point out, @thefourtheye

Answer (score 5):

Using [Dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (one-liner; if you didn't have the two concerns):

```
result = {key: {"index": index} for index, key in enumerate(yourList)}
```

You can use it like:

```
>>> yourList = range(10)
>>> result = {key: {"index": index} for index, key in enumerate(yourList)}
>>> result
{0: {'index': 0}, 1: {'index': 1}, 2: {'index': 2}, 3: {'index': 3}, 4: {'index': 4}, 5: {'index': 5}, 6: {'index': 6}, 7: {'index': 7}, 8: {'index': 8}, 9: {'index': 9}}
```

For a solution that accounts for those two bullets, I'd suggest something like the below:

```
result = {}
for index, item in enumerate(yourList):
    currentDict = {"name": "wow", .. all your other properties .. }
    currentDict["index"] = index #Or may be myFunc(index)
    result[item] = currentDict
```

*NOTE*: I hope you are using hashable items in your original list.

Comment: Please allow me to try your answer later, will get back to you. Thanks for your help.